# Xcode 11 option clicking on source files to open them next to the active editor doesn't work

Tags: xcode, catalina

So, The weirdest thing happened to me...

I got a problem with not being able to option click a source file to open it next to the source file I'm working on.
Weird.... So, I booted back into my pre-catalina OS, and tested there. Option click works there.
So, back to Catalina beta. Created a new user account. Switched to that account, started xcode, created a new project and voila. Option click works. I thought I knew the fix: Use the new user account and work from there. So I open the project I was working on and...... No more option click to open a source file next to another source file.

So, on the same machine, same partition, same XCode, same XCode settings (!!!), I can use option clicking in projectONE on source files to open them next to the active editor, but not on projectTWO.

What could be the problem?

[image: Screenshot of my navigation settings.]

Comment: Can you go to Xcode Preferences → Navigation and verify the Optional Navigation setting?

Comment: Yes, I've added a screenshot showing my settings. Weird thing is, it works in another project, but not in the project I need to work on.

Comment: Here's what the defaults look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QWsd.png Try tweaking the values of Navigation and Optional Navigation.

Comment: Those don't look like Xcode 11 settings, but It works in one project but not the other. So the settings in the Navigation Preferences seem to be good. Something else must be interfering. What could be happening in one project to block the functionality?

Comment: My bad I fail to notice that you are using Xcode 11. The screenshot is from Xcode 10.

Comment: Right now, I think it's just a beta thingy, but my colleagues do not experience the same problem so I thought I would ask different.